# query json api inside a sql fetch array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

Is there a way to check a sql fetch array row against a json api? I need to cycle through 1000's of row's but pull a variable from a json api for each row.

I tried putting my json code inside my while statement but that does not work.

The sql statement gives me my data from the database but I need to get the $json_prop for each row entry from the json api.

```
   <?php $tsql2 = "SELECT *
             FROM customer
             where cust_no < '33000' and customer.status = '8'";         
         $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql2); 
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
{  


//echo $json_prop['Records']['0']['AreaLotSF'] . 'areasq';
       print "<tbody>
    <tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['cust_no']. "</td><td>" .$row['firstname'] ." ".$row['lastname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['size'] . "</td><td>" . $json_prop['Records']['0']['AreaLotSF']. "</td>" ;  
}  
//close
?>
```

php json code that works for a single entry

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$query = array(
  "id" => ""
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,
  "https://www.exampleurl.com/v2/lookups/property/?address=123+street+rd&city=San Jose&state=CA&zip=00000"&fmt=json&id=key"
  
);


$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$json_prop = json_decode($response, true);
echo curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: What's the output of the response when you call json api inside the `while` loop?

Comment: _"but that does not work"_ - and "doesn't work" does not work for us, as a substitute for an _actual_ problem description.

Comment: Warning: curl_exec(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in, but if I move the json curl call outside the while loop, I get data

Comment: It may be possible that I need to stop the loop confirm a response then move to the next row in the loop is that possible? When I do a single entry from the sql select the json takes a few secs to get the data

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what  I did but it works, returns the sql rows and the variable from the json API for each sql row entry.

```
 <?php $tsql2 = "SELECT *
                 FROM customer
                 where customer_number = '45350'";        
             $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql2); 
             
                   
             //Loop though results
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
    {  
        
       $url = "https://url/v2/lookups//?address=".$row['streetno']."+".$row['streetname']."+".$row['suffix']."&city=".$row['city']."&state=".$row['state']."&postalCode=".$row['zip']."&fmt=json&id=**";
       $url = str_replace ( ' ', '%20', $url);
       $url = trim($url); 
        
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    //echo $resp;
    //echo curl_exec($curl);
    $json_prop = json_decode($resp, true);
                                      
    
    curl_close($curl);
    
    $adjusted_size = $json_prop['Records']['0']['AreaLotSF'] / 1000;
    $percentChange = (1 - $row['size'] / $adjusted_size) * 100;
    
           print "<tbody>
          <tr>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['cust_no']. "</td><td>" .$row['firstname'] ."   ".$row['lastname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['size'] . "</td><td>" . round($adjusted_size, 0) . "</td><td>". $percentChange. "</td>" ;  
           
      }
      //close
    ?>
```